# AlertDialog box Repeats four times

Tags: java, javascript, android, nfc, android-alertdialog

OK my question is a lot bigger than the Title. But can't describe everything in a Title. So here we go.

I am writing an App that when a NFC cards get detected by Phone, it will be able to WRITE and READ a NDEF message on / from it.

I use two buttons READ and WRITE to trigger these events. Everything works fine, just the thing that **EVERYTHING REPEATS ITSELF FOUR (4x) TIMES!**

Only the TAG "UltraLightCard Detected" and "Connected" pops once.
Everything else that you see in code in "ShowMessage" will pop out 4x times also the AlertDialog box gets triggered 4x times and you have to write the text 4 times. 
If you wrote it only once and then clicked "Save" 3x times just to close it, it wont store the string.

**Here's my code:**

```
protected void ultralightCardLogic() {
    final Button b_write = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_write);
    final Button b_read = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_read);

    b_write.setId(1);
    b_read.setId(2);
    //showImageSnap(R.drawable.ultralight);
    ShowMessage("UltraLight Card Detected :" + mifareUL.getTagName(), 'a');

    try {
        mifareUL.connect();
        mifareUL.formatT2T();
        ShowMessage("Connected!" , 'd');
        b_write.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        b_read.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**Here is MyTouchListener:**

```
public class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stu
        int id = v.getId();
        switch(id){
            case 1:
                onCreateDialog();
                break;
            case 2:
                readNDEFmsg();
                break;
            case 3:
                break;              
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Here is the OnCreateDialog:**

```
final View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dia_box,null);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setView(v)
    .setPositiveButton("SAVE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final EditText mEdit=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.et_dia);
            String str = mEdit.getText().toString();
            writeNDEFmsg(str);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

If you guys need some more of the code, I can add it then. Don't want to write too much code, because my experience tells me that then noone will try to help me out.

Please, help me out

Comment: Am I right that You added a TouchListener to the button? Why not using onClickListener?

Comment: ^^^ i just thought the same thing

Comment: Oh man. It could be that indeed! I will try with on Click Listener guys and report back ASAP!

Comment: no, not the same. Just try it with the clickListener, I am not sure if this is causing Your behaviour, but it could be. Because onTouchListener fires more than one action, like onPressed() onReleased() etc.

Comment: when I want to setOnClickListener it says that I have to implement following argument:
`(android.view.View.OnClickListener)`  . When I run the App the "Write" button does not trigger anymore now.

There's a warning in LogCat tho:
`java.lang.ClassCastExceptio: MyClickListener cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener`

Comment: Yes, I posted the answer below :)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to your help I figured out my issue.

I used `onTouchListener`, which triggers more than once, since it has more MotionEvents available.

After I changed on to `OnClickListener` everything works smoothly!
Just be sure to **implement** `View.OnClickListener` 
if you are doing it like I do in my public `class MyClickListener`.

Then Eclipse will auto-generate your necessary code. Extract the id of your buttons and do the switch statement (again, if you`re doing it this way):

```
public class MyClickListener implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int id = v.getId();
            switch(id){
            case 1:
                onCreateDialog();
                break;
            case 2:
                readNDEFmsg();
                break;
            case 3:



                break;

            }

        }
```

Thanks again for the help! Hope it will help someone else too.